# Return Mat from dll, got AccessViolationException error

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I wrote a simple test try to pass Mat from dll, the dll part is like this:

```
namespace testerDll {

cv::Mat getmat()
{
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);

    static cv::Mat im;

    capture >> im;

    //cout<<"get image"<<endl;

    //imshow("test",im);
    return im;
}

int testfun()
{
    return 1;
}
```

}

And I use this dll in another project, code is like this:

```
cv::Mat im = testerDll::getmat();

int i = testerDll::testfun();

cout<<i<<endl;

while(true)
{
    imshow("im",im);

    int k = cv::waitKey(20);
    if(k>0)
        break;
}
```

When running, the imshow() function cause "AccessViolationException" error,
I tried another function testfun() from dll and it works fine.

I tried to search solution on internet, but could not find any solution that can
solve this...
I`m pretty new to C++, so this might be a stupid mistake...

Could anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Please do not post image of text.  Post text as text.

Comment: @MartinBonner There are two image links in the question body: http://i.stack.imgur.com/76Q1N.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/0LgRv.png

Comment: So there are.  However the OP has entered the actual text.  How strange.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am first time ask here,  and I forgot to delete the pic...